# Initializing session variable from query result Laravel

Tags: laravel, session, syntax, initialization

FatalErrorException
Can't use function return value in write context. Is this some syntax problem or what?

```
        $result1 = Some query here
        $result2 = Some query here
        $result3 = Some query here

//error start here
        session('sessionVariable1') = $result1 
        session('sessionVariable2') = $result2 
        session('sessionVariable3') = $result3
```

Comment: you cannot assign the result of a function, you should use it as dbr below shows you: put the var in an array and pass it to the `session` helper

Answer (score 3):

Check the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/session#storing-data).

```
// Via the global helper...
session(['key' => 'value']);
```